# Placing a text with coordinates with drawText()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to place a text with coordinates, but i don't know how to introduce the arguments.

I searched in the net and that only has examples with Qt.Allign ----, and if I place the arguments as in the documentation, I got error.
It is built with PyQt5 in python 3.6

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer, Qt, QRectF
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor, QFont, QPainter


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.stopwatch()

    def stopwatch(self):
        hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(hbox)
        self.setWindowTitle("Example")
        self.setGeometry(400,400,400,200)
        self.formato = "0:00.0"
        self.show()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qp = QPainter()
        qp.begin(self)
        self.draw_rect(event, qp)
        qp.end()

    def draw_rect(self,event, qp):
        # Black Rectangle
        col = QColor("Black")
        col.setNamedColor("Black")
        qp.setPen(col)
        qp.setBrush(QColor("Black"))
        qp.drawRect(130,000,400,200)
        # formato
        qp.setPen(QColor("Green"))
        qp.setFont(QFont('Helvetica', 48))
        qp.drawText(event.rect(), QRect(50, 50, 50, 50),5 , self.formato)  # Problem 


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = Window()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

QPainter offers several options to draw a text:

```
void drawText(const QPointF & position, const QString & text)
void drawText(const QPoint & position, const QString & text)
void drawText(const QRectF & rectangle, int flags, const QString & text, QRectF * boundingRect = 0)
void drawText(const QRect & rectangle, int flags, const QString & text, QRect * boundingRect = 0)
void drawText(int x, int y, const QString & text)
void drawText(int x, int y, int width, int height, int flags, const QString & text, QRect * boundingRect = 0)
void drawText(const QRectF & rectangle, const QString & text, const QTextOption & option = QTextOption())
```

In your case you should use:

```
qp.drawText(QPointF(50, 50), self.formato) # first option
qp.drawText(QPoint(50, 50), self.formato)  # second option
qp.drawText(50, 50, self.formato) # fifth option
```

**Note:** The error that causes the window to close is because the parameters that you have passed do not correspond to any of the forms.

Comment: Thanks again, sorry for the novice questions

Comment: @DanielRestrepo Do not apologize for that, if my answer helps you do not forget to mark it as correct. If you do not know how to do it, check the following link: [tour]